# How do I bind a observable list of name|values in Forms?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to bind a observable list containing a simple object with name and value to display in list or stack layout inside a Xamarin.Forms application.

The listView for whatever reason did not allow me to edit the content.

```
<ListView x:Name="lstEstablishmentType" Grid.Row="0"  ItemsSource="{Binding States}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                    <Entry Text="{Binding Value}" />
                                </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>        
        </ListView>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, things are displayed but I can't change value.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "I can't change value". What value are you trying to change and by what means?

Comment: As you maybe able to see there is a Entry control, that is bound to the property "Value". Thats what I need to be able to edit and add some other value. When I touch the textbox (Entry), I do not get the keyboard as I would if it was outside the listviews template.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out...

The version of Xamarin.Forms that comes with the project by default has a bug decribed in the link below

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=25948#c5

By updating the package to v1.4 the problem went away.